# Unable to locate uploaded file to in google drive

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I have used googleapi node.js to uplaod pdf files, I ues drive.file.insert function for that. I got file ID is response, But I'm unable to locate the file in google drive. 
I also used drive.files.get, this function give me url to the uplaoded file. but when I used to go to that link, it me to request for permission.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Not pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for not being able to find a file after you have uploaded the file and can see the file response after the upload is that you are using a service account for authentication.  This would also lead to you not having access to the file when you try to use the link the file is owned by the service account not you.

After checking the response you have posted I can see that the owner is in fact a service account

[image]

service accounts are dummy users they have their own drive account so when you upload a file it will be uploaded to the service accounts drive account.  You have a few options.

1. have the service account share the file with you by inserting permissions.
2. Grant the service account access to a folder on your personal drive account and instruct the service account to upload the file to that directory by setting the parent in the upload.
3. leave the file on the service accounts account.

Comment: Yes, Its a service account. I tried to grant service account access to the personal folder. but still its same. Secondly How can I open google drive of service account. I have created this service account using credentials page on google api dashboard